# Adding a column in dataframe based on another column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

Add an bool column based array of string column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists` function for Spark 2.4+:

```scala
val df = customerDocument.withColumn(
  "flag",
  expr("exists(address, x -> x rlike 'test string')")
)
```

For older versions, you can convert the array into string then use `rlike`:

```
val df = customerDocument.withColumn(
  "flag",
  concat_ws(",", col("address")).rlike("test string")
)
```

Example:

```
val df = Seq(
  (Seq("ADR249,IND0100,300", "Purcell Road", "Road Town", "British Virgin Islands,300,Purcell Road,Road Town,British Virgin Islands")),
  (Seq("ADR500,IND0268,425", "High Street", "Sydney", "Australia,425,High Street,Sydney,Australia"))
).toDF("address")

df.withColumn(
  "flag", 
  concat_ws(",", col("address")).rlike("British Virgin Islands")
).show(false)

//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
//|address                                                                                                                |flag |
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
//|[ADR249,IND0100,300, Purcell Road, Road Town, British Virgin Islands,300,Purcell Road,Road Town,British Virgin Islands]|true |
//|[ADR500,IND0268,425, High Street, Sydney, Australia,425,High Street,Sydney,Australia]                                  |false|
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

##### EDIT

For your specific spark version (<2.1), you can't use `concat_ws` to convert array into string. You need to use `DataFrame.map` like this:

```
df.map(r => {
  val address = r.getList(0).toArray.mkString(",")
  (address)
}).toDF("address").withColumn(
  "flag",
  col("address").rlike("British Virgin Islands")
).show(false)
```